# Drupal: Is safe adding uid=0 in users table just to use $_SESSION?

Tags: php, drupal

I read many articles about adding it, but I'm not encouraged to use it yet. People says that Drupal don't add this user because MySQL Auto-increment starts at 1. So, about adding uid=0, is it a good practice? Is it widely used? What possible problems could I have with it? Thanks. :)

Comment: You may consider asking this question on the Drupal Answers site: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, we recommend using this uid as uid = 1, 
always corresponds to the admin, this can cause problems. 
What is the purpose of using that uid?

Answer (score 1):

There is already a user 0 in the users table which is the anonymous user.